# How to raise a key to ultimate trust on another machine?

Tags: pgp, gnupg, openpgp

I have created a master key with two subkeys: one for signing and the other for encryption. Finally, I have exported the two subkeys to a new machine.

How can I tell the new machine to consider the master as "ultimate", even if it is absent from the machine? Does it matter?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can set every key to ultimate trust through opening the key edit command line

```
gpg --edit-key [key-id]
```

and running the `trust` command. You will now be prompted to select the trust level:

```
Please decide how far you trust this user to correctly verify other users' keys
(by looking at passports, checking fingerprints from different sources, etc.)

  1 = I don't know or won't say
  2 = I do NOT trust
  3 = I trust marginally
  4 = I trust fully
  5 = I trust ultimately
  m = back to the main menu

Your decision?
```

Obviously, `5` will be the proper decision to achieve ultimate trust. Finally, `save` to commit the changes and exit GnuPG. The same commands apply to both GnuPG 1.4 and GnuPG 2 (and newer).

Ultimate enables a key to introduce trust in the OpenPGP web of trust, with other words all ultimately trusted keys act as a starting point for trust paths. You should set your own keys to ultimate trust, but usually will not do so for other's.

Comment: Minor note: it seems that `save` is not necessary, giving 'Key not changed so no update needed.'

Comment: You're right, in fact this does not really edit the _key_, but the _trust database_ which does not seem to require the `save` command.

Answer (score 14):

To change the Ownertrust trust level of a key after importing in a simplier way (without the interactive `--edit-key` mode) I found this way in one line using `gpg --import-ownertrust`:

According to this mail [from the Gnupg-users mailing list](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2010-July/039219.html) the trust level can be changed using `gpg --import-ownertrust`

You only need to get the `fingerprint` of the key and the `trust level number` which is the `trust level number` you use in the `gpg --edit-key [key-id]` `trust` `trust level as 1,2,3,4,5` ... `+ 1` (Don't ask me why but I have tested each level)

```
1 = I don't know or won't say => will be = 2
2 = I do NOT trust => will be = 3
3 = I trust marginally => will be = 4
4 = I trust fully => will be = 5
5 = I trust ultimately => will be = 6
```

To change Ownertrust trust level to `ultimate` as example:

Get the fingerprint of the key (public or private) if already imported (if not use `gpg --with-fingerprint mykey.gpg` to get fingerprint before importing the key)

```
gpg --list-keys [key-id]
gpg --list-secret-keys [key-id]
```

Change the Ownertrust trust level by echoing `FINGERPRINT:LEVEL:` to `gpg --import-ownertrust`

```
echo "07C9F77F0E8134E64A7FF0AA666B4C8DC27B4A0A:6:" | gpg --import-ownertrust
```

See the new Ownertrust trust level of the key

```
gpg --list-keys [key-id]
gpg --list-secret-keys [key-id]
```

You can export your Ownertrust trust level of all keys before or to backup them

```
gpg --export-ownertrust > trustlevel.txt
```

And reimport them if needed

```
gpg --import-ownertrust < trustlevel.txt
```

Using `gpg --import-ownertrust` you can set the Ownertrust trust level of a key before importing the key and then the key will be trusted according to the trust level defined after import operation or import the key and then change the trust level of the imported key.

Comment: the echo could also be automated using `sed`to add the trust like `sed -E -n -e 's/^fpr:::::::::([0-9A-F]+):$/\1:6:/p'`

Comment: I built a scripted version out of your answer:
`keyid=$(gpg --quiet --import-options import-show --import $key | sed -e '2!d' -e 's/^[ \t]*//') &&  echo "${keyid}:6:" | gpg --import-ownertrust`

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to automate this (`gpg --edit-key`; `trust`; `5`; `save`) for newly imported keys, effectively importing them as ultimately trusted.

```
$ gpg --import <key.asc
$ (echo 5; echo y; echo save) |
  gpg --command-fd 0 --no-tty --no-greeting -q --edit-key "$(
  gpg --list-packets <key.asc |
  awk '$1=="keyid:"{print$2;exit}')" trust
```

Comment: Great because it works inside (bash-)scripts, so I can automate the import, without iteraction with the terminal

Comment: Awesome answer! GPG is so difficult to use programatically. Workarounds like this make it usable.

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on @pts's answer and rewrite it such that the input variables are more clearly defined.

```
# Given a keyfile
KEY_FPATH=key.asc
# Extract the public key ID
KEY_ID=$(gpg --list-packets <"$KEY_FPATH" | awk '$1=="keyid:"{print$2;exit}')
# Modify the trust level of the key-id
(echo 5; echo y; echo save) |
  gpg --command-fd 0 --no-tty --no-greeting -q --edit-key "$KEY_ID" trust
```

I will also add an alternative answer that I've been using, which uses the `exepct` tool.

```
# Set the key-id you want to modify
KEY_ID=...
# The following modifies the trust level without interaction
expect -c '
spawn gpg --expert --pinentry-mode loopback --edit-key "$KEY_ID"
expect "gpg> "
send "trust\r";
expect "Your decision?"
send "5\r";
expect "Do you really want to set this key to ultimate trust? (y/N)"
send "y\r";
expect "gpg> "
send "save\r";
interact
'
```

However, I like @pts's answer better because it does not require the `expect` tool, which does not come pre-installed on most linux distros.